# jquery select parent table rows only

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hi I have table inside that table I have one more table. How to write jquery selector to get only parent table rows?

```
<table class="required_capacity">
<tr>
    <td>Row1</td>
    <td>Row1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Some Text ... </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some Text ... </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Row 3</td>
</tr>
```

in above html code I need get only $('.required_capacity') table rows. I tried this selector to get rows

```
$('.required_capacity_table').children('tr')
```

but it gives in side table rows also?

Comment: This class name is used in another table then its also get tr of another table so you can use id of table (Apply id in your table).

Comment: thanks Harry I tried with id also no use, it returns inner table rows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.required_capacity_table > tbody > tr')
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jCEkx/)

Comment: I tried this also getting same results. results include inner table rows i need to only outer table rows

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
$('.required_capacity_table > tr')
```